# Adding WS-Security Credentials to SOAP headers using WCF

Tags: wcf, soap, ws-security, soap-client, wsse

I am trying to communicate with a Java web service that I have no control over, and I'm trying to create a binding that'll work.

1. Timestamp is not allowed in the header, so in order to use the `includeTimestamp="false"` attribute, I have to use a `<customBinding>`.
2. They are using MTOM, so I have to use the `<mtomMessagingEncoding>` element.

Here is my `<bindings>` element:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding >
    <binding name="MyBindingName" >
      <mtomMessageEncoding  />
      <transactionFlow />
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                includeTimestamp="false">            
      </security>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

The SOAP web service requires that the message header be in the following format:

```
 <soap:Envelope ... >
  <soap:Header ... >
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsse:Username>doo</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">fuss</wsse:Password>
    </...>
  </...>
 </...>
```

The closest I have come is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
            xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1"></a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:a368e205-a14d-4955-bf75-049cdd3a78c0</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://blablabla</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" 
                xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-0f1e399b-31a8-4e00-a57f-277c21e94879-1">
      <o:Username><!-- Removed--></o:Username>
      <o:Password><!-- Removed--></o:Password>
    </o:UsernameToken>
   </o:Security>
 </s:Header>
```

I am sure I'm missing something trivial and stupid here, but for the life of me i can't figure out what it might be.

Comment: What happens when you use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I did use the "Add Service Reference", but the WSDL doesn't contain any ws-security information.

Comment: Amazing the number of organizations who don't get that the WSDL is meant to describe the service. Is there any explanation for this? Like, maybe the security is implemented by something outside of the service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must also configure message version because by default it uses WS-Addressing:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding >
    <binding name="MyBindingName" >
      <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" /> <!-- or Soap12 -->
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                includeTimestamp="false">            
      </security>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

`TransactionFlow` element is not needed at all.

Btw. message you showed is not valid usage of WS-Security token because it must be inside `Security` element so if it is really what Java service expects it doesn't conform to WS-Security specification and you will have to use custom message header instead.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the <wsse:UserNameToken> element should have a <wsse:Security> parent (according to the spec)?  If this is so, I can get them to change their implementation.  Where would I find a reference for this?

Comment: ... implemented your changes and it works as expected - I see the <Security> element as you said.  I'll talk to the Java dudes and see if they can't get it corrected.  Thanks!